# Using the same dataset and algorithms, WEKA application and source code validation results don't match

Tags: java, algorithm, validation, machine-learning, weka

Using the source code in http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/a-simple-machine-learning-example-in-java/ , I've run the java application.

Then I've installed the WEKA 3-8-1 (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html) and run the same algorithms (J48, PART, DecisionTable, DecisionStump) and dataset (Weather.txt). However, I get different validation results. For example, for J48, I get %50.0 accuracy using the WEKA source code whereas I get %64.3 accuracy using the WEKA application.

[image: WEKA Source Code Validation Results]

[image: WEKA Application Validation Results]

Same if I use other algorithms, I don't get the same validation results either.

Can anyone explain me why I don't get the same accuracy results?

Note: I am using 10-Fold Cross-validation for each.